# Eclipse for C/C++ Oxygen version sometimes doesn't react on Ctrl+click

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have an issue with new version of Eclipse (CDT). I had previously Eclipse Neon. It worked fine, but I noticed a new version, Oxygen, and wanted to use it.

I downloaded Eclipse Oxygen and started it. It said that my version of workspace was created with older version of Eclipse and it must update the workspace to new version. I agreed.

After that, when I was walking through my code, I noticed that in some classes, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-left-click on class name, it doesn't jump to the class definition. I am sure that it worked fine previously with Neon. I also know that I can use <kbd>F3</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-left-click, but I like clicking and dont' want to search for the <kbd>F3</kbd> key on the keyboard every time (it is faster for me to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on the class name). Surprisingly, in other places of my code, the functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-left-click still works as expected. I don't know what happened. Something is clearly broken.

I checked if creating workspace from scratch helps, but not, when I removed `.metadata` directory and created everything again, the problem still exists. In some places <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-left-click works, in other not. <kbd>F3</kbd> always works.

It is very annoying. I remember that I had this problem before when I was upgrading my Eclipse, downloaded a new version and this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-left-click stopped working. So it is not only about the Oxygen version. I am wondering - do I do something wrong here?

Did you have a similar problem before? I tried googling the problem but with no success.

Comment: Could you give an example of a class where Ctrl+left-click does not work, but F3 works?

Comment: I cannot paste the code, it is my company's code. But for example when I have a local Mock (GMOCK) class in my test, I can jump to it using F3, but not using CTRL-leftclick.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding index? I think Oxygen suffers from both indexing and syntax parsing regressions. I have to launch indexing manually even more often than before. Parsing of template static variables definitions got completely broken and such places are now always highlighted as syntax error.

Comment: I tried rebuilding index, it didn't help.

Comment: Sometimes I think this Eclipse sucks. The sad thing is that I tried almost all other free IDEs and no one was better for me than shitty Eclipse. Sometimes I envy my Java friends because they have this IntelliJ IDEA fantastic IDE. Why doesn't C++ have anything like that? It is so unfair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sound like [**Eclipse bug 517610**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517610).

See [comment 5](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517610#c5) for a workaround:

> [To work around the problem, you can disable the Change Log hyperlink by going to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Hyperlinking, then untick "Changelog Detector".](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517610#c5)

The bug fix is scheduled for Oxygen.1, which will be released on September 27th 2017. Alternatively, you can update to latest development build (which should already contain the fix) via the update site `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/master/nightly`.

Comment: Wow, it helped! Thank you so much! :-)) Wow :-)) I didn't expect anyone could help me with this. Thanks a lot!